# TFS build process detects error, Visual Studio build process doesn't give an error

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, tfs

My solution can be built properly, with no errors on my workstation while the same source gives an error when building with TFS.

The solution projects target .NET 4.0 and I use VisualStudio 2012 on the workstation.
Using tfs.visualstudio.com (tfspreview.com) to keep the source, which I tried building with the Hosted Build Controller on tfspreview and with my own Build Controller that I host with TFS 2012 on my server.

I get the error in code where I use dynamic `ExpandoObject`.

Why my solution can't build on TFS?

I can provide more details if needed.

Comment: What's the error code and error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post this as an answer as it solved this strange problem.

One of the project's solutions had two separate references to same open source library. One  to the downloaded precompiled library, and one to another project where I kept the source of the same library. The first one was added by Nuget, the second manually.

**The possibility to actually do this (add two references of same assembly) was probably a bug in Visual Studio or Nuget.** Later when I tried to reconstruct this bug, an error message appeared, saying there is already reference to the specific assembly name.

**For the compiling**, I understand that TFS build agent considered only the precompiled assembly (Nuget package) and threw an error.

Visual Studio considered the assembly source which I modified to use with ExpandoObject.

Calling build command manually produced the same error as TFS did.

I removed both references and added only one (the other couldn't be added again anyway). That equalized the build behavior of TFS and VS for my solution.

I know this is very odd and I still can not remember how that double reference bug occurred in the first place. My guess is, this error can be reconstructed by editing the .proj file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the hosted build to see if that works?

Is is definitely the expandoobject? if you comment out that code does the build succeed?

can you send an excerpt from the build log?

Comment: There was a problem with References in one of the solution's projects. I re-added the references and the same error showed in VS IDE also.